# How to share XML element to several XML parents node?

Tags: xml, google-apps-script

I'm trying to create three XML files at the same time (A, B, and C) with shared values. Unfortunately, when I try to assign a group of elements to three differents parents, code returns a non-explicit error at the second parent defined.

And I don't know how to create a "reel" copy of an element.

I worked around the problem by creating the code three times but it's non-productive.

```
var XMLrootA = XmlService.createElement('root');
var XMLrootB = XmlService.createElement('root');
var XMLrootC = XmlService.createElement('root');
var XMLsource = XmlService.createElement('source');
  XMLsource.addContent(XmlService.createElement('reference').setText('toto'));
XMLrootA.addContent(XMLSource);
XMLrootB.addContent(XMLSource);
XMLrootC.addContent(XMLSource);
```

I expect `XMLrootB` and `XMLrootC` to hold the same value(s) as `XMLrootA` but, apparently, multi-affectation is forbidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You want to create multiple xml data using copying the elements.
- You want to make `XMLrootA`, `XMLrootB` and `XMLrootC` have the same structure with `XMLsource`.
- `XMLSource` of `XMLrootA.addContent(XMLSource)`, `XMLrootB.addContent(XMLSource)` and `XMLrootC.addContent(XMLSource)` is the same with `XMLsource`.

  - This is due to the miscopy when you posted the question.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

#### Modification points:

- In your situation, I used `cloneContent()`.
- At first, it creates `XMLrootA`. Then, each element is copied to `XMLrootB` and `XMLrootC`.

#### Modified script 1:

If your script is modified, as simple modification, how about the following modified script?

```
var XMLrootA = XmlService.createElement('root');
var XMLrootB = XmlService.createElement('root');
var XMLrootC = XmlService.createElement('root');
var XMLsource = XmlService.createElement('source');
XMLsource.addContent(XmlService.createElement('reference').setText('toto'));
XMLrootA.addContent(XMLsource);

// I modified below script.
var copy1 = XMLsource.getParentElement().cloneContent();
for (var i = 0; i < copy1.length; i++) {
  XMLrootB.addContent(copy1[i]);
}

var copy2 = XMLsource.getParentElement().cloneContent();
for (var i = 0; i < copy2.length; i++) {
  XMLrootC.addContent(copy2[i]);
}
```

#### Modified script 2:

In this modified script, the method for copying is modified from above script.

```
var XMLrootA = XmlService.createElement('root');
var XMLrootB = XmlService.createElement('root');
var XMLrootC = XmlService.createElement('root');
var XMLsource = XmlService.createElement('source');
XMLsource.addContent(XmlService.createElement('reference').setText('toto'));
XMLrootA.addContent(XMLsource);

// I modified below script.
var root = [XMLrootB, XMLrootC];
root.forEach(function(e) {
  var copy = XMLsource.getParentElement().cloneContent();
  copy.forEach(function(f) {
    e.addContent(f);
  });
});
```

#### Note:

- This is a simple sample script. So please modify this for your situation.

#### References:

- [Class XmlService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/xml-service)
- [cloneContent()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/element#cloneContent())

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Hi Tanaike, thank you for considering my question. You saw that I made a mistake in my copy/paste code with the XMLsource variable, sorry about that. I do agree with your answer but why it's so difficult just to use a same "object" to share it with several others? It's a "forced" limitation from Google ? Why can't we use "reference" or "pointers" that would do the trick? Because, in that case, the code become really long and you can't split parts into functions that would be eaiser to understand and maintained... Regards.

Comment: @Aymeric Gavend Thank you for replying. I think that about the reason for using ``cloneContent()``, when ``XMLrootA.addContent(XMLsource)`` is run, ``XMLsource`` might be changed (at this time, ``source`` is added as the parent.). Because when ``cloneContent()`` is run without running ``XMLrootA.addContent(XMLsource)``, the copied object is different (at this time, ``source`` is not added as the parent.). You can also confirm it.

Comment: @Aymeric Gavend I think that by this, the method of ``cloneContent()`` is added for copying object. So it is considered that this might be the specification at Google side. If my answer and comment were not useful for your situation, please tell me. I have to remove my answer, because I don't want to make other users confuse.